# get List<HashMap> from createSqlQuery in hibernate without Pojo or Scalar

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I am trying to convert SQL query return types (list) to list, but as of now, i am getting, list of Object[]. Is there is any method to convert it directly to List without the help of Pojo, adding scalar or HQL?

My Current abstract query method is

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT UI.idea_id, UI.user_id,UI.title, UI.innovators
FROM user_idea AS UI  
WHERE UI.status=1 AND CONCAT(';',UI.innovators,';') like '%;jack;%';";
        try {
            Query query = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
            if (values != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    query.setParameter(i, values[i]);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I found the solution as there is no pre defined function to do it. First I retrieved all the columns from the query and then made a hashmap with column_name(key) and queryResult(value). select * from.. should be avoided, instead give required column names in query in order to get the result from given function.

```
public List<Map> queryResultToListMap(String query, List queryResult) {
        int indexOffrom = query.indexOf("from");
        int indexOfselect = query.indexOf("select");
        String subquery = query.substring(indexOfselect, indexOffrom);
        subquery = subquery.replace("select", "");
        String[] arr = subquery.split(",");

        List cols = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            String[] subarr = arr[i].split(" ");
            cols.add(subarr[subarr.length - 1]);
        }
        List<Map> colswithdata = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator itr = queryResult.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            HashMap colsWithData = new HashMap();
            Object[] tempArray = (Object[]) itr.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
                colsWithData.put(cols.get(i), tempArray[i].toString());
            }
            colswithdata.add(colsWithData);

        }

        return colswithdata;
    }
```

Comment: I liked the shortcut method, even though there are some outbound exceptions happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Test.class));
```

Comment: in this case, we need to have a bean which represents the MySQL result row, and it also it will be difficult to have beans every time for custom queries. I am looking for another solution. Thanks